# Regex to match subfolder inside of a domain

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently using `\/[^\.]+$` to match subfolders within url.

I'm wondering how I can modify it to only match with the subfolder substring.

It's currently recognizing the http:// and https:// protocol but I do not want that to be a match.

demo: https://regex101.com/r/nG7kM9/12

example:

```
thisisatest.com => no match
https://thisiatest.com/ => no match
http://thisiatest.com/folder/folder2/ => /folder/folder2/ match
http://thisisatest.com/folder => /folder match
https:// => https:// match ( but don't want this to match )
http:// => http:// match ( but don't want this to match )
```

Comment: Let me know output you want.

Comment: @hongarc I'm looking to recognize subfolders in domains www.test.com/folder1/folder2 output to `folder1/folder2/` which is working with the regex above.

But the problem is it's working with protocols with `https://` and `http://` as well, I do not want that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(?<!\/)\/[^\/\.][^\.:]*$
```

- `(?<!\/)\/`: match `/` but don't match `//`
- `[^\/\.]`: don't match `.` as you want, don't match `/`after a character `/`
- `[^\.:]*`: don't match `.` as you want, don't match `:`

**Note**: you don't want match `.`, but I think that it can mistake with URL have `.`, can you add all case you want? I change the regex to help you

Answer (score 0):

You could first match the http protocol with an optional s and `://`

Then use a negated character class `[^\/\r\n]+` to match any char except `/`

In the capturing group match a forward slash followed by matching any char except a newline 1+ times `(\/.+)` to prevent the single slash at the end to match.

The value is in the first capturing group

```
^https?:\/\/[^\/\r\n]+(\/.+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6a0nSx/1)

```js
const regex = /^https?:\/\/[^\/\r\n]+(\/.+)$/gm;
const str = `thisisatest.com
https://thisiatest.com/
http://thisiatest.com/folder/folder2/
http://thisisatest.com/folder
https://
http://
`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  console.log(m[1]);
}
```